# searching html files in directories using python

Tags: python, html, search, path, directory

I have an html parser function and it needs absolute path for each file.

How do I search a directory and find only files ending with .html and then return the absolute path of each file?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the python os module? It has the listdir(path) command

```
os.listdir(path)
Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

Availability: Unix, Windows.
```

Use it to get all the files names in your directory, filter out the non-html files, and then prepend the path to the directory to get the absolute path.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html